# Detecting a server conversion in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

Can I - and if so, how do I - detect in Google TM **either** one of these cases:

1. A new HTML element (in this case, img) was suddenly appended to the webpage.
2. A certain JavaScript AJAX command was suddenly launched and returned a success (with a non empty data).

In other words, can I detect when the following is triggered?

```
function verify(...
 $.ajax({...
        success: function (data...
            if (data) {...
                if (data.imagePixelUrl) {
                    $("#footer").append("<img id='imagePixel' src='" + data.imagePixelUrl + "'/>");
                }
```

If it's triggered, it means there was a conversion in my landing pages.
Here's the full flow of these LPs:

1. The visitor fills their phone number and clicks submit
2. If the number is incorrect, the server returns an error and the client displays it
3. If the number is correct, the server returns a success the visitor is sent SMS with a password
4. The visitor fills their password and clicks submit
5. If the password is incorrect, the server returns an error and the client displays it
6. If the password is correct, the server returns a success and appends an img tag to the webpage (i.e. we have a conversion)

### Working example

- **Landing page**: http://goo.gl/A7Lpny
- **Phone number**: 111111
- **Password**: 222222
- **AJAX path**: http://goo.gl/m5ARX3 (reminder: we need to find if AJAX success in *function verify* was triggered in this JS URL).
  AFAIK, the only thing that's truly unique there is the aforementioned append command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way would be to amend your ajax function to push variables to the dataLayer and then use those in the tag manager:

```
    function verify(...
     $.ajax({...
            success: function (data...
                if (data) {...
                    if (data.imagePixelUrl) {
                        $("#footer").append("<img id='imagePixel' src='" + data.imagePixelUrl + "'/>");
    dataLayer.push({
    'event':'datapixel',
    });
}
```

Then you would create an event based trigger (event equals datapixel) to fire your tags.

If for some reason you cannot change your function you might use a global ajax event handler with jquery as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910368/google-analytics-track-exits-within-a-one-page-checkout/22913808#22913808).

Comment: I'm a little hesitant about injecting **dataLayer.push** in lots of places. What if our websites later stop using TM?

Comment: Then you have an unused variable in your page. That might be a little clutter, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Here's how to then capture the event and then turn it to a GA goal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099665/