# How can I turn dataLayer.push into a Google Analytics Goal?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I like to turn

```
window.dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'Offer', 'vpv': '/offer-lead'});
```

or

```
window.dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'Offer', 'eventCategory': 'Success', 'eventAction': 'Lead', 'eventLabel': pageId});
```

into a GA Goal that shows people who I count as "leads".

I managed to catch this event in TM but not in GA.
Can you please take me to the needed steps in both TM and GA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> window.dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'Offer', 'vpv': '/offer-lead'});

Here's the solution I eventually came up with:

1. 1. I created a Trigger of a Custom Event set to Fire On "Offer".
   2. I created a Data Layer Variable called "vpv".
   3. I created a GA Tag of "Page View" with "More Settings=>Fields to Set" of "page" set to the Data Layer Variable from step 2.
      I set it to Fire On the trigger from step 1.
2. In GA, I created a Destination Goal for the path of "/offer-lead".

Answer (score 3):

You need two things.

1) Tie together *dataLayer* with *Google Analytics* in *TagManager*. So you have to create new **Tag** for Google Analytics type **EVENT**. You set up **Property ID** and event parameters such as **Category**, **Action** and **Label**. All of them set up as macro/variable type DataLayer and point them to your key names in dataLayer push (eventCategory, eventAction and eventLabel).
Firing rule should be more generic than event equals Offer, rather user **event** **equals** **fire** or something more generic. You can re-use the Tag for all other events.

2) Set up Google Analytics. There create **new goal** from **event** and set **Category** to *Success* and **Action** to *Lead*.

This is it.

Comment: +1 for this. But just wondering why event should be more genetic. If the event was too generic and common for different things, then you can risk accidental firings and goal conversions.

Comment: @herr-kreuz, by **Property ID** do you mean **Tracking ID**? Could you please provide more details on how to "point them to your key names"? Thanks!

Comment: @nyuen - **every** event consists of **2-5 default** parameters. It is Category, Action, Label, Value(int) and non-interaction flag. When you define **all** of these parameters **via** macro/variable pointing to **dataLayer**, you can use only one Tag for milions of different usecases. You only change dataLayer.push values in eventCategory, evetAction, eventLabel, eventValues, eventNonInt variables.

Comment: @LWC - yes, it is Tracking ID (GTM terminology) and Property ID (UA Terminology) it is the same. You can either use some macro/variable to set it in multiple tags. 

**Pointing:** in GTM new macro/variable set some name like eventCategory set type to DataLayer variable and version v2 or v1 (in you case it does not matter) and variable name is eventCategory (from you initial question JavaScript array push )