# Modifying existing JavaScript in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

Can I use Tag Manager to change this line:

```
function verify(...
        $.ajax({...
   ...
          success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (data) {
   ...
                   if (data.imagePixelUrl) {
                        $("#footer").append("<img id='imagePixel' src='" + data.imagePixelUrl + "'/>");
```

to this:

```
function verify(...
        $.ajax({...
...
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (data) {
...
                   if (data.imagePixelUrl) {
                        $("#footer").append("<img id='imagePixel' src='" + data.imagePixelUrl + "'/>");
                        dataLayer.push({'event' : 'success'});
```

?

The new line is the **dataLayer.push**. Note it's inside a success call of an AJAX command.

Comment: I just mentioned in an answer to your first post that jQuery has global ajax event handlers that you can use in a custom html tag - you do not necessarily need to change your existing code, you can hook into the ajax success event.

Comment: You referred me there [to this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910368/google-analytics-track-exits-within-a-one-page-checkout/22913808#22913808).
But my URL has multiple AJAX commands with success/error, so how do I link to the success of *function verify* and not any other function?

Answer (score 0):

Use the global a[jax event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/) in jQuery, specifically the success handler. To discern between your different functions you can i.e. check the settings.url (i.e. the url you called to make your ajax request which is presumably different per function). E.g.:

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url == "ajax/urlone.html" ) {
     dataLayer.push({'event' : 'verfiy'});
  } else  if ( settings.url == "ajax/urltwo.html" ) {
     dataLayer.push({'event' : 'function two'});  
 } else {
     dataLayer.push({'event' : 'default'});  
 }
});
```

**Update**: I just found a sort-of-solution for the same question asked on Linkedin (I assume asked by the same person), so I might as well add it here. "Sort-of-solution" because it does not answer the question but solves the problem.

As the added pixel is an image and an image has an onload event one can simply attach an function to the onload handler of that image.

```
<script> 
$('#imagePixel').on('load',function() { 
alert("I am pixel hear me roar"); 
}); 
</script>
```

This fires as soon as the image is appended. I tested this with  simple setup and it seems to work nicely.

Comment: xhr and settings are objects with many properties - surely something in there if different between functions (many the returned content - xhr.responseText ?). If not this is not possible and you have to manually change your jQuery function.

Comment: Appended a possible solution.

Comment: Can I assume you mean **dataLayer.push** replaces the **alert**?

`<script>`
`$('#imagePixel').on('load',function() {`
`dataLayer.push({'event' : 'success'});`
`});`
`</script>`

Comment: Yes (although of course you can put any kind of js function in there).

Comment: someone else told the following - what do you think?
That would require the image with the ID #imagePixel to exist when that jQuery is executed, since you can't attach listeners to elements that don't (yet) exist. So you would still need to have access to the script on the page to add the .on() method and at that point it's easier to just add the dataLayer.push()."

Comment: That "someone else" was me. You can set up events in jQuery so that they will be attached to dynamically created elements using the on() function (http://api.jquery.com/on/). The image does not need to exist, the on function will observe if images are created and fire the onload accordingly.